# n characters before and after substring

Tags: regex, perl, bash

I'm looking for a way (preferably bash or perl) to extract a substring from a longer string so that n characters before and after the substring are included. I'd like to search for, say

```
XXXXXXX
```

within

```
....NNNNAAAAXXXXXXXAAAANNNNNNN....
```

and include the As but not the Ns, so the return string would be

```
AAAAXXXXXXXAAAA
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

A better example (maybe):
I have a file with a list of unique strings,

```
UniqueStr1
UniqueStr2
UniqueStr3
...
```

And a file with the same number of lines containing, e.g.

```
JUNKJUNK_start1_UniqueStr1_end1_JUNKJUNKJUNK
JUNKJUNKJUNKJUNK_start2_UniqueStr2_end2_JUNKJUNKJUNK
start3_UniqueStr3_end3_JUNKJUNK
...
```

And I'd like to return a file containing

```
start1_UniqueStr1_end1
start2_UniqueStr2_end2
start3_UniqueStr3_end3
...
```

Comment: Is number of A's you want to print static? So that you, can say you always want 5 chars before and 4 after?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, that's right.

Comment: Then, can you post a more general example so we get the idea better?

Comment: What if number of around characters is less than required? Ex.: `ABXXCD` and you want 4 characters from each side of `XX`?

Comment: Additional question: what if you have `ABXXCDXXEF` string and you search for `XX` with 2 characters around. Do you expect to capture `ABXXCD` and `CDXXEF`?

Comment: `UniqueStr1` in `start3_UniqueStr1_end3_JUNKJUNK` - is it typo or not?

Comment: The 'XX..' string will always be unique and there will always be more than n characters at the start and end, so it doesn't matter :)

Comment: Why is this question put on hold? The question is obvious?!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
my $string = 'NNNNAAAAXXXXXXXAAAANNNNNNN';

if ( $string =~ /.{4}XXXXXXX.{4}/ ) {
    print $&;
}
```

In case, the substring before the mentioned substring (in this case AAAA) and the substring after the mentioned substring are always the same this is also another way to do it.

```
my $string = 'NNNNAAAAXXXXXXXAAAANNNNNNN';

if ( $string =~ /(.{4})XXXXXXX\1/ ) {
    print $&;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear exactly how you want to defined the core string, the prefix, and the suffix. But this short piece of code will do what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  print "$1\n" while /(.{0,7}UniqueStr\d.{0,5})/g;
}

__DATA__
JUNKJUNK_start1_UniqueStr1_end1_JUNKJUNKJUNK
JUNKJUNKJUNKJUNK_start2_UniqueStr2_end2_JUNKJUNKJUNK
start3_UniqueStr1_end3_JUNKJUNK
```

**output**

```
start1_UniqueStr1_end1
start2_UniqueStr2_end2
start3_UniqueStr1_end3
```

---

**Update**

If you want to read the data from external file, say `patterns.txt` and `data.txt`, it would look like using a fixed pattern `UniqueStr\d` for the core string, it builds a regular expression from the contents of `patterns.txt` using the alternation character `|`. The strings are all mapped through `quotemeta` so that they still work if they happen to contain any regex metacharacters.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'patterns.txt';
my @patterns = <$fh>;
close $fh;
chomp @patterns;
my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @patterns;
$re = qr/(.{0,7}(?:$re).{0,5})/;

open $fh, '<', 'data.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  print "$1\n" while /$re/g;
}
```

The output is identical to the above

Comment: +1 for the `__DATA__`. Every time I see one of your Perl answers there's a part of it that shows something completely new!

Comment: @TomFenech: Thanks. The `DATA` file handle is mostly useful only for test programs to save creating a separate file with sample data. A couple of things about it: you can use `__END__` in the same way and your `DATA` handle will still work fine; it is just a handle to the current source file, with the file pointer initially set to the start of the line after `__DATA__`, so if you `seek DATA, 0, 0` then your program can read its own Perl source.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just found them in the [Special Literals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) section of perldoc.

Answer (score 1):

This snippets extracts the target you specified and it leaves you the option to select only the result and/or the margin. In the seconds option you can also make sure, that the left margin and the right margin are identical.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

#
# Set the Parameters...
#
my $target = 'XXXXXXX';
my $margin = 4;


#
# Set Position an __DATA__ for later use
#
my $datapos = tell DATA;

#
# Search __DATA__ for a target with arbitary margin...
#
say "=== Option I ===";
while ( <DATA> )
{
    while( /(.{$margin})($target)(.{$margin})/g )
    {
        my $left_margin     = $1;
        my $result          = $2;
        my $right_margin    = $3;

        say $left_margin.$result.$right_margin;
    }
}

#
# Restart reading from __DATA__ at the beginnen
#
seek DATA, $datapos, 0;


#
# Search __DATA__ for a target with matching margin...
#
say "=== Option II ===";
while ( <DATA> )
{
    while( /(.{$margin})($target)\1/g )
    {
        my $left_margin     = $1;
        my $result          = $2;
        my $right_margin    = $1; # Left and right margin are the same

        say $left_margin.$result.$right_margin;
    }
}

exit;

__DATA__
NNNNAAAAXXXXXXXAAAANNNNNNNNNNNBBBBXXXXXXXBBBBNNNNNNNCCCCXXXXXXXCCC
NNDDDDXXXXXXXDDDDNNNNNNNNEEEEXXXXXXXEEEENNNNNNNFFFFXXXXXXXFFFFNNNN
NNNNGGXXXXXXXGGGGNNNNNNNNNNNHHHHXXXXXXXHNNNNNNNIIIIXXXXXXXIIIINNNN
```